# Do Windows Domain Controllers broadcast anything to a remote server connected via VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, vpn, domain-controller

Our Windows 2003 Server web server (my responsibility) is in another city and talks to a database server on our LAN (the LAN is someone else's responsibility) via a VPN. The VPN is established via a hardware firewall on each end. When the LAN Domain Controllers do their  broadcasts, would the remote web server get them?

Comment: What broadcasts are you worried about? A vanilla DC with only AD DS and DNS installed won't do any more broadcasting than any other Windows server.

Comment: @Tim do you mean AD replication instead of broadcasts?

Comment: @squillman I thought that at first too, but it doesn't sound like there is a DC at his end. He's worried about traffic between the DCs and a web server.

Comment: @MDMarra, yeah I was asking so as to clarify how it all works if necessary.

Comment: @squillman, *any* kind of broadcasted traffic, sorry if my terminology misled. I am looking for ways to explain periodic 100% CPU consumption on the web server, which I've not seen ever before on that server (in about 5 years).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain Controllers don't do any broadcasts that are unique to Active Directory. Just standard ARPing, the occasion NetBIOS, and whatnot. If the VPN at both sites spans a single broadcast domain, then broadcast traffic will traverse the link, unless the VPN endpoints are explicitly configured to drop broadcast traffic.

[This TechNet article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;179442) breaks down all of the AD-specific services that need ports to be open between clients and DCs. As you can see, none of these protocols, other than NetBIOS, are broadcast-based and NetBIOS traffic happens on all Windows-based machines unless you explicitly turn it off.